# IF conditional formula in VBA - Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba

I am getting a Run-time error '1004' at the line with IF statement. Checked the previous posts, but could not find a relevant solution.
My code is

```
Sub RefreshFormulae()
Set sh = ActiveSheet
lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sh.Range("$J$3:$K$" & lastR).ClearContents
sh.Range("$H$3:$H$" & lastR).Formula = "=$G3"
sh.Range("$K$3:$K$" & lastR).Formula = "=IF($I3<>""Not Found"";$I3;"""")"
End Sub
```

Error is in the line below. Am I missing anything here?

`sh.Range("$K$3:$K$" & lastR).Formula = "=IF($I3<>""Not Found"";$I3;"""")"`

Comment: Has been asked so many times here on SO, but too tired to look for the best fitting duplicate. In VBA, you need to specify your formula in the english format, replace `";"` with `","`

Comment: @FunThomas -  got you covered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use commas when entering formulas in VBA, even when you use semicolon directly in the sheet.

```
Sub RefreshFormulae()
Set sh = ActiveSheet
lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sh.Range("$J$3:$K$" & lastR).ClearContents
sh.Range("$H$3:$H$" & lastR).Formula = "=$G3"
sh.Range("$K$3:$K$" & lastR).Formula = "=IF($I3<>""Not Found"",$I3,"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! 
As pointed out here ; was creating the problem

Comment: You only need to use commas if you're using `.Formula`. Your first sentence is misleading, since `.FormulaLocal` with `;` is entirely possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a comma (`,`) instead of a semicolon (`;`) in VBA, as the regional format for separators inside functions only works in the Excel formula bar interface, not macros/VBA.

Try:
`"=IF($I3<>" & Chr(34) & "Not Found"",$I3,"""")"`

This would make the whole block change to:

```
Sub RefreshFormulae()
Set sh = ActiveSheet
lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sh.Range("$J$3:$K$" & lastR).ClearContents
sh.Range("$H$3:$H$" & lastR).Formula = "=$G3"
sh.Range("$K$3:$K$" & lastR).Formula = "=IF($I3<>" & Chr(34) & "Not Found"",$I3,"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know why this answer was upvoted. Problem of OP is *not* quotes, they are correct. Problem is you need to use comma, not semicolon

Comment: Updated accordingly, thanks @FunThomas

Comment: yes, replacing ; with , solved the problem. thank you

Comment: Your first sentence is misleading. `;` works with the `Local` versions: `.FormulaLocal`, `.Formula2Local`, etc.